# Codeigniter- How to insert different sizes of arrays into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I want to insert data in table 'projects'. I have two  arrays with different sizes, they are

```
$advisor_id = array(
         'id' =>1
         'id' =>2
         'id' =>3
      );


$project_id = array(
      'pid'=>1
      'pid'=>2
      'pid'=>3
      'pid'=>4
   );
```

My code is:

```
$advisors = count($this->input->post('advisor_id[]'));   
$PM_ids = count($this->input->post('PM_id[]'));
if($advisors > $PM_ids){
    $count = $advisors;
}else{
    $count = $PM_ids;
}

$data[] = array();
for($i =0; $i<$count ; $i++){
    $data = array(                      
          'advisor_id' =>$this->input->post('advisor_id')[$i],
          'PM_id' =>$this->input->post('PM_id')[$i],
    );     
    //print_r($data);
    $this->db->insert_batch('project_config',$data);     
}
```

My problem is the different sizes of arrays. How can I insert into database.

Comment: In the above example data, what is your desired output (or table after insert)?

Comment: i need to insert  two arrays with different sizes  to database table

Comment: I see that from your title, but that doesn't help us understand what the actual goal is. From what I see above, you want 4 entries, but I'm not sure what you want the 4th value of `advisor_id` to be.

Comment: Both arrays are illegal format. They can't contain an index more than one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy to submit `NULL` values where missing, `array_map()` is the best tool for the job.

First a general demonstration of how/where `NULL` elements are generated when array size mismatches occur...

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6746e89917dd1d9aa2f0110eb004ce1fc75d81e1))

```
$advisor_id=['id1'=>1,'id2'=>2,'id3'=>3];
$project_id=['pid1'=>1,'pid2'=>2,'pid3'=>3,'pid4'=>4];
$data=array_map(function($id,$pid){return ['advisor_id'=>$id,'PM_id'=>$pid];},$advisor_id,$project_id);
var_export($data);  // see how NULL elements are formed in the output array
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'advisor_id' => 1,
    'PM_id' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'advisor_id' => 2,
    'PM_id' => 2,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'advisor_id' => 3,
    'PM_id' => 3,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'advisor_id' => NULL,
    'PM_id' => 4,
  ),
)
```

The above multi-dimensional array is now fully prepared for a single [insert_batch()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data) call.  **IMPORTANT** CodeIgniter's `insert_batch()` is specifically designed to INSERT multiple rows of data at once -- to use this call inside of a loop defeats the purpose of making this call.

As for you actual implementation, this should work (I don't code in CodeIgniter):

```
$data=array_map(function($id,$pid){return ['advisor_id'=>$id,'PM_id'=>$pid];},$this->input->post('advisor_id'),$this->input->post('PM_id'));
$this->db->insert_batch('project_config',$data);
```

CLEAN & DONE: No for loops, no `$i` counters, and just one call to the database.

Comment: Thanks for improving the code and the nice documentation. Much appreciated :-)